# Find repeating substring within two substrings with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following kind of string `"sdfds asd bsd bsd bsd cdf sadasd"`. The number of `"bds"` can vary. I want to extract `"asd bsd bsd bsd cdf"`.

I used the following expression `"(asd)\s(bsd)*\s(cdf)"`

Comment: The `\s` should be inside the repeating group `(asd)(\sbsd)*\s(cdf)`

Comment: that only gives me `"asd bsd cdf"`, but I want `"asd bsd bsd bsd cdf"`

Comment: You get 3 capture groups, where the full match is `asd bsd bsd bsd cdf` see https://regex101.com/r/HKdtFW/1 If you don't want capture groups `\basd(?:\sbsd)*\scdf\b` https://regex101.com/r/8xET2v/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a match only, the pattern could be without capturing groups (as repeating a capture group keeps only the value of the last iteration), and match the leading whitespace char in the repetition.

The word boundaries prevent a partial word match.

```
\basd(?:\sbsd)*\scdf\b
```

Example

```
import re

s = "sdfds asd bsd bsd bsd cdf sadasd"
pattern = r"\basd(?:\sbsd)*\scdf\b"

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
asd bsd bsd bsd cdf
```